# Add a blur listener to a Vaadin layout

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a custom field which consists of a `TextField` and a `Button`

[image]

I use this control to make a label editable. When user clicks on an edit button beside the label, label gets removed from UI and this component gets inserted to the place where the label was. This custom field initially has focus.

When the focus is lost from the custom field, I need to remove the custom field and insert the label again (discarding the edit).

I tried by adding a blur listener to the encapsulating `TextField`. It works fine except for this one problem: if I clicked on the save button, since the `TextField` looses focus, the custom field gets removed.

If I can add a blur listener to the `HorizontalLayout` in which both the `TextField` and `Button` contains, this would get resolved. But it is not possible to add a blur listener to the layout.

Any idea how I can get this done?

Comment: Since the Layout does not have the focus, you can't have a blur listener. In what order are the blur and the click listeners called? Perhaps you can do something when regarding this order

Comment: Regardless of the order the listeners were added, blur listener gets invoked before click listener

Comment: Then readd the textfield when you receive the Clickevent

Comment: Just a wild thought, would the [pop up view](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/popup-view) component suit your needs? What you're trying to do sounds awfully similar to it. [Here's](https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/demo/sampler/src/com/vaadin/demo/sampler/features/popupviews/PopupViewContentsExample.java) a more explicit sample code.

Comment: @Morfic Thanks for pointing out the information. It looks like a good alternative